# Adding comment by anonymous user creates error in blog

Tags: comments, nodes

I created a blog using Drupal 7. Admin can add and display comments correctly. But when an anonymous user adds comment, then this was not shown in the unapproved list and the blog page shows error. Already approved comments will be shown in the approved list. But newly unapproved comments from anonymous user won't display. If I delete the unapproved comments from database the blog page works fine. I gave permission to anonymous user to post comments. Anyone please help me.

Comment: Please share what the error you are getting.

Comment: Only shows 'Unexpected error appears' message in the screen.

Comment: Visit the recent logs in reports and check whether you can find anything related to it.

Comment: Hi, we're going to need at least an error message to go on or this is impossible to answer I'm afraid

Comment: Error shows only when admin login to the site. Before login blog page works fine.